# How to delete Listview items using jquery in asp.net

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I am working on an application in asp.net in which i have an Listview and in that listview there in an another listview. In the inner listview i have a linkbutton which is used delete items of inner listview. i want to delete items of inner listview usig jquery.The design portion of my program is:

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListView5" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="ListView5_ItemDataBound">
 <ItemTemplate>
   <li>
      <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upcom" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
      <ContentTemplate>
   <asp:Image runat="server" Style="width: 50px; height: 50px;" ID="Image1" ImageUrl='<%#Eval("Image") %>' />
  <asp:HiddenField ID="lblWallID" runat="server" Value='<%#Eval("Wall_ID") %>'></asp:HiddenField>
  <p>
     <h3>
          <a href="Profile.aspx?ID=<%#Eval("UID") %>">
          <asp:Label ID="lbl1" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Full_Name") %>'></asp:Label>
           </a>
    </h3>
 </p>
 <p>
   <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Wall_Content") %>'></asp:Label>
</p>
<p>
   <asp:Label ID="lblTime" CssClass="time-text" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("TimeAgo") %>'></asp:Label>
   <asp:LinkButton ID="btnClick" runat="server" Text="Comment" OnClick="btnClick_Click" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("Wall_ID") %>' CommandName="Comment"></asp:LinkButton>
</p>
<p>
    <ul>
        <asp:ListView ID="listWallComments" runat="server" >
        <ItemTemplate>
         <li>
            <asp:Label ID="lblWallComment" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Comments") %>'></asp:Label>:-
            <a href="Profile.aspx?ID=<%#Eval("User_ID") %>">
            <asp:Label ID="lblFullname11" runat="server" CommandName="Profile" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("User_ID") %>' Text='<%#Eval("Full_Name") %>'></asp:Label>
            </a>
            <asp:LinkButton ID="lbtnDelete" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("Comment_ID") %>' onclick= OnClientClick="Confirm('Are u sure to delete?') %>)">Delete</asp:LinkButton>                                                              
                                                                                   </li>
    </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:ListView>
    </ul>
    </p>
</ContentTemplate>
  <Triggers>
      <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnClick" EventName="Click" />
 </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
</li>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

the code to delete inner listview item is :

```
protected void lbtnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            ListViewDataItem gdr = (ListViewDataItem)((Control)sender).NamingContainer;

                LinkButton linkComment = (LinkButton)gdr.FindControl("lbtnDelete");
                long ID = Convert.ToInt64(linkComment.CommandArgument.ToString());
                retval = new Process_WallComment().DeleteComment(ID);
                if (retval > 0)
                {
                    Bind();
                    Response.Write("<script>alert('Deleted')</script>");
                }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw(ex);
        }
    }
```

but my code refresh the page during the deleting. I want to delete the item of inner listview using jquery.Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

So you want to remove the list in which the delete button is contained?

You can try this sample:

```
<li>
//your other markup here
// then the delete button
<button onclick="removeList(this)"> </button>
</li>
```

The javascript function

```
function removeList(btn){
// add delete confirmation here , if true continue else return from the function from here.
btn.parent().remove();
// this will remove the parent element of the button. ie the list item.
//do not add "runat=server" as this is client side operation and the page should not post //back.
}
```

Comment: i want to delete item from database also and also after deleting i want to bind listview with datasource of datatable using jquery.is that possible .If yes,then please help me to do that

Comment: You can create a separate asp.net page which would accept the list id from query string and perform delete actions on the database and reload the new list in it.    then you can do an ajax call from the function removeList() to that page with query string, and in response read the new list created on the other page and display it back.

Comment: I am not an asp.net guy but I think asp:update panel should just work